# Setencia Where no me funciona con UNION, JOIN entre otras

Tags: php, mysql, php7, join, union

tengo ese código que funciona perfecto.

```
SELECT * FROM novedad N RIGHT JOIN empleados E
ON  N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado JOIN area A
ON E.area_id=A.id_area WHERE MONTH(fechaactual) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
UNION (SELECT * FROM novedad N
RIGHT JOIN empleados E
ON  N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado
JOIN area A ON E.area_id=A.id_area
WHERE MONTH(f_actual) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()))
```

[image: Vean que hay datos en el campo licenciatipo1]
Hay registros en la celda licenciatipo1

ese código lo que hace es traer todos los registros de todas las tablas del mes actual, pero lo que quiero es agregar una sentencia a este mismo código que traiga solo los registros de las personas que pidieron licencia por enfermedad, o sea el campo 'licenciatipo1' sea igual a 'Licencia por enfermedad' que esta en la tabla novedad, pero no me trae nada.

Ya probé poniendo

```
    SELECT * FROM novedad N WHERE licenciatipo1='Licencia por enfermedad'
```

y no me trae nada.

No se donde estoy fallando.

Sera que tendría que crear otra tabla que diga 'LICENCIAS' y ahí cargar todo tipo de licencia.

¿Sera eso?

Ya use el `SELECT * FROM novedad N WHERE licenciatipo1 like '%Licencia por enfermedad%'`

eso solo si funciona, pero cuando agrego al código completo me da error de sintaxis.

```
SELECT * FROM novedad N WHERE
licenciatipo1 like '%Licencia por enfermedad%' RIGHT JOIN empleados E`ON  N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado JOIN area A`
ON E.area_id=A.id_area WHERE MONTH(fechaactual) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
UNION (SELECT * FROM novedad N
RIGHT JOIN empleados E
ON  N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado
JOIN area A ON E.area_id=A.id_area
WHERE MONTH(f_actual) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()))
```

Así me da error de sintaxis.

Comment: No se entiende podrias agregar un ejemplo?

Comment: lo que quiero es traer todos los registros donde el campo licenciatipo sea igual a 'Enfermedad'., osea quiero mostrar solamente los que pidieron una licencia por enfermedad, porque existe varios tipos de licencia de trabajo. Se entiende?

Comment: y probaste poniendo en el where eso?

Comment: Valida que no tengas espacios en tu base de datos, ya que si estas ejecutando: `SELECT * FROM novedad N FROM licenciatipo='Por Enfermedad'` y no te muestra datos, llegaria a pensar que existe algun espacio o salto de linea.
Como ultima opción realiza un backup de la base y restaurala.

Comment: @Cristhian si logras ejecutar una query que tenga 2 from sos dios... esa query directamente no esta bien...

Comment: @Cristhian borrar una base de datos y restaurarla no es nunca la solucion a un problema en una query.. .si la query no devuelve nada, debe ser porque no hay datos que devolver. cuando hay un problema con la db, la misma db lo informa...

Comment: Si esa query no trae nada, es que no hay nada que se parezcan a esos datos. A ver si agregas un ejemplo que demuestre que tenes de esos datos en la db...

Comment: Ahi les explique un poco mas

Comment: Como dijo @Cristhian, try SELECT * FROM novedad N WHERE licenciatipo1 like '%Licencia por enfermedad%'

Comment: SI, así funciona, pero cuando agrego a la sentencia completa me sale error de sintaxis

Comment: Y porque pusiste el where ahi en lugar de donde va?

Comment: Donde iria? ya puse en todos lados

Answer (score 0):

En tu consulta  **SELECT * FROM novedad N WHERE licenciatipo1='Licencia por enfermedad'**

Intenta esto `SELECT * FROM novedad N WHERE N.licenciatipo1=TRIM('Licencia por enfermedad')`

Para eliminar los espacios que hayan a los lados.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM novedad N ' RIGHT JOIN empleados E`ON  N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado JOIN area A`
ON E.area_id=A.id_area WHERE MONTH(fechaactual) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
WHERE licenciatipo1 like '%Licencia por enfermedad%

UNION (SELECT * FROM novedad N
RIGHT JOIN empleados E
ON  N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado
JOIN area A ON E.area_id=A.id_area
WHERE MONTH(f_actual) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())) and licenciatipo1 like '%Licencia por enfermedad%

Comment: pon los where bajo el la consulta principal y bajo el union y tendría que funcionar

Comment: También probé así y me sale error de sintaxis

Comment: fijate el ultimo parentesis, tiene que ir abajo de todo...................
SELECT * FROM novedad N ' RIGHT JOIN empleados EON  N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado JOIN area A ON E.area_id=A.id_area WHERE MONTH(fechaactual) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) WHERE licenciatipo1 like '%Licencia por enfermedad%

UNION (SELECT * FROM novedad N RIGHT JOIN empleados E ON N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado JOIN area A ON E.area_id=A.id_area WHERE MONTH(f_actual) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) and licenciatipo1 like '%Licencia por enfermedad%)

Comment: Muchas Gracias..

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos, ahi me funciono asi:

```
SELECT * FROM novedad N RIGHT JOIN empleados E
ON  N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado JOIN area A
ON E.area_id=A.id_area WHERE MONTH(fechaactual) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
and licenciatipo1 like '%Licencia por enfermedad%'
UNION (SELECT * FROM novedad N
RIGHT JOIN empleados E
ON  N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado
JOIN area A ON E.area_id=A.id_area and licenciatipo1 like '%Licencia por enfermedad%'
WHERE MONTH(f_actual) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()))
```

Asi funciona perfecto, use en AND

Gracias a todos